# tr1::regex regex_search problem

Tags: regex, search, matching, tr1

I'm using tr1::regex to try to extract some matches from a string. An example string could be

```
asdf werq "one two three" asdf
```

And I would want to get out of that:

```
asdf  
werq  
one two three  
asdf
```

With stuff in quotes grouped together, so I'm trying to use the regex `\"(.+?)\"|([^\\s]+)`. The code I'm using is:

```
cmatch res;
regex reg("\"(.+?)\"|([^\\s]+)", regex_constants::icase);
regex_search("asdf werq \"one two three\" asdf", res, reg);

cout << res.size() << endl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++k) {
    cout << res[i] << endl;
}
```

but that outputs

```
3
asdf

asdf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your regex engine does not support lookbehind assertions. To avoid using lookbehinds, you can try the following:

```
"([^"]*)"|(\S+)
```

or quoted:

```
"\"([^\"]*)\"|(\\S+)"
```

This regex will work, but each match will have two captures, one of which will be empty (either the first -- in case of a non-quoted word, or the second -- in case of a quoted string).

To be able to use this you need to iterate over all matches, and for each match use the non-empty capture.

I don't know enough about TR1, so I don't know exactly how one iterates over all matches. But if I'm not mistaken, the `res.size()` will be always equal to 3.

For example, for the string `asdf "one two three" werq` the first match will be:

```
res[0] = "asdf"              // the entire match
res[1] = ""                  // the first capture
res[2] = "asdf"              // the second capture
```

The second match will be:

```
res[0] = "\"one two three\"" // the entire match including leading/trailing quotes
res[1] = "one two three"     // the first capture
res[2] = ""                  // the second capture
```

and the third match will be:

```
res[0] = "werq"              // the entire match
res[1] = ""                  // the first capture
res[2] = "werq"              // the second capture
```

HTH.

Comment: How then would I get the matches thing like you said if I'm using an iterator? You use an iterator in the style of for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator i(str.begin(), str.end(), reg); i != end; ++i) { cout << *i; } You don't really get a choice as to whether you get the entire match, first capture or second capture, that I can see.

Comment: What about the following: `for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator i(str.begin(), str.end(), reg); i != end; ++i) { cout << ((*i)[1] || (*i)[2]); }`? I cannot check if this compiles, let alone runs, but the idea is that `*i` is an object that has an indexing operator, which should give you the captures.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following regex instead:

```
(?<=")[^"]*(?=")|[^"\s]\S*
```

When quoted, it of course needs to be escaped:

```
"(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|[^\"\\s]\\S*"
```

Btw, the code you used probably matches only the first word in the target string, since it does not use match_any. The 3 items you are getting in the result are probably (1) the entire match, (2) the first capture -- which is empty, and (3) the second capture, which is the source of the match.

Comment: Actually when I use that regex, when I run the program, this is outputted to the console: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact..." blah blah blah, and it crashes.

Comment: I don't have a working environment where I can check this, but I've tested the regex with both Java and C#, and it didn't crash neither. Please use syntax_option_type=extended to make sure it follows the standard syntax for extended regexes.  
  
(BTW, I made a small fix to the first part of the regex to prevent it from capturing a space after the end of a quoted word.)

Comment: You're invited to play with the regex here: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=a9e366fd

Comment: I changed it to regex reg("(?<=\")[^\"]*(?=\")|[^\"\\s]\\S*", regex_constants::syntax_option_type::extended); and I got that error again :( Any idea why?

Comment: Wierd error: no matter what regex I use, the regex_constants::syntax_option_type::extended always makes it crash. If I take that out and remove the (?<=\") from your regex, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Confirmed, regex_constants::extended makes all regexes crash. Without any second argument, I can use your regex if I take out the lookbehind, but that yields incorrect results.

Comment: I understand. Okay, there's another option, which is slightly more complicated but doesn't require a lookbehind assertion. I will add it in a few minutes to the solution above.

Comment: If I use "\"(.+?)\"|([^\\s]+)" and for (std::tr1::sregex_token_iterator i(str.begin(), str.end(), reg); i != end; ++i), iterator style, it works fine except when it matches something in quotes, it includes the quotes for some reason.

Comment: Yeah, because you get the entire match, which includes the quotes. See the explanation in the other solution I've posted.

Comment: BTW, `\"[^\"]*\"` is better than `\".*?\"` because it (1) catches also \n inside the quotes, and (2) is somewhat faster. Also, `[^\\s]` is equivalent to `\\S`.